# Extracting the Top 5 values of a criteria into a new sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've done a search but I haven't found exactly what I'm looking for.

Is there a way to extract the `top 5` of a criteria into a new sheet? As an example, see please see screenshot below.

Ideally if I was making a report on `Sample School 14`, I would like the `Top 5` ranked schools in `B Sample Council` to which that school belongs to, to be extracted to a new sheet.

I would then go on to recreate this for each quarter

An example of the datasheet and location as below.

If there was also a Macro that could be created it would be great.

***Example Screenshot:***
[image]

Comment: Post data as text instead of screenshot so that we can copy to our spreadsheet.

Comment: This is exactly the reason why the `Large()` worksheet function has been invented: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/large-function-3af0af19-1190-42bb-bb8b-01672ec00a64#:~:text=Description,%2C%20or%20third%2Dplace%20score.

Comment: You can do this with Pivot Tables. Google for Pivot Tables Top 5 and you'll find examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With <kbd>Excel O365</kbd> you can use-

```
=INDEX(SORT(FILTER(Sheet1!A2:E11,Sheet1!D2:D11="B Sample Council"),5),SEQUENCE(5),SEQUENCE(,5))
```

[image]

Comment: I finally got to use the above and it worked perfectly - MASSIVE time saver. Thanks so much.

Comment: @Len If it works then please consider accepting the answer (Tick mark it).